# How to change the mouse cursor's size?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a Widows program in which I need a 1×1 cursor. I used `LoadCursorFromFile()` on a .cur file, but it got enlarged to the standard cursor size.
I also tried the following:

```
wc.cursor = LoadImage(0, "Cursor.cur", IMAGE_CURSOR, 1, 1, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

^`wc` is the window class.

In this case,  I got a compiling error which says that it can't convert `hIcon` to `int` or such, and I can't figure out what's wrong.
The program uses OpenGL, but unfortunately, I can't conveniently place a dot at the cursor's location, because I disabled glClear() since it's a drawing program.
**Any idea on how to texture the cursor with a 1×1 white square?**

Answer (score 0):

LoadImage returns a HANDLE.  I assume by `wc.cursor` you're referring to the `hCursor` field of a WNDCLASS struct, which is an HCURSOR.  Depending on the level of your compiler settings you may need to explicitly case the HANDLE returned by LoadImage to HCURSOR for this assignment to work.

There's not much to go on in the question, but there are several other things that can go astray here.  Once you get it compiling, you might want to check the return value from the LoadImage to make sure it actually loaded the cursor.  If it failed (indicated by a NULL or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), check GetLastError, which might have a clue as to the problem.

A simple approach might be to design a standard size cursor that has just one opaque pixel.